# How does scp traffic flow between two remote hosts?

Tags: sftp, rsync, scp

If you issue a **scp** command between 2 remote servers, will the traffic flow directly between the hosts, or will it flow from Remote1 => Local Machine => Remote2?

For example I issue this command on my laptop:

```
scp user1@remote1.com:/Files user2@remote2.com:/Files
```

Answer (score 25):

Newer versions of scp (since 2011) have the option `-3` which will route the traffic through your local machine. This is useful if the hosts are on different networks and can't see each other. [Found this on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/315358/scp-between-two-networks). From your linked article it seems like normally the hosts will try to connect directly to each other.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it can be [done](http://gwynconnor.blogspot.com/2010/04/copying-files-between-two-remote-hosts.html).

Answer (score 0):

If your linux/bsd/unix or Mac do not have the `-3` option, just compile the last version from: http://www.openssh.org/portable.html

It is as simple as:

```
./configure; make ; sudo make install
```

It will be installed on `/usr/local/bin` by default. I just did that on my Mac OS X Lion.